# Intellij not stopping at breakpoints after several runs

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I'm running a web application but after several calls to the HTTP endpoint, Intellij ignores the breakpoints I set and just runs the code. I can tell because my log messages are getting printed despite the debugger not stopping at the breakpoints.

My breakpoint is set on the method and several executable steps so they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a rather obscure problem somehow, but I figured it had something to do with me

1. Sending requests before I wait till the `'Waiting until last debugger command completes'` message to go away.
2. Cancelling requests (because no return message is sent even after waiting for a long time) and sending them again.

When I do wait, there will be no problems in the debugger stopping at the breakpoints on my next call.

Not too sure why it happens, but slow down the request calling and only call after that message goes away to prevent this from happening.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544799. Debugger logs may reveal more details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for the links. I'm having issues trying to run Intellij from the command line. I get this error: JetBrains\IntelliJ was unexpected at this time. Also, I'm not sure how the running from the command line thing would work as I'll need to run my program on a local tomcat server.